Why do I receive an error when calling my invoke Endpoint
I keep running into error trying to generate content from my AWS endpoint using GPT2..
import os
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

# Set AWS credentials using environment variables
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "key"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "secret key"

# Configure the timeout settings and retry attempts for the Boto3 client
config = Config(
    read_timeout=300,  # Increase the read timeout to 300 seconds (5 minutes)
    connect_timeout=60,  # Increase the connect timeout to 60 seconds
    retries={'max_attempts': 5}  # Increase the maximum number of retry attempts to 5
)

sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
runtime_client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker', config=config)

# Replace 'gpt-2-model' with the actual name of your deployed GPT-2 model
gpt2_model_name = 'gpt-2-model'

# Replace 'gpt2-endpoint' with the actual name of your SageMaker endpoint
endpoint_name = 'gpt2-endpoint'

# Get information about the deployed GPT-2 model
try:
    gpt2_model_info = sagemaker_client.describe_model(ModelName=gpt2_model_name)
    print("GPT-2 Model Information:")
    print(gpt2_model_info)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error retrieving GPT-2 model information: {e}")

# Get endpoint information
try:
    endpoint_info = sagemaker_client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
    endpoint_config_name = endpoint_info['EndpointConfigName']
    print("Endpoint Information:")
    print(endpoint_info)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error retrieving endpoint information: {e}")

def generate_content(prompt, max_length=500):
    try:
        response = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(
            EndpointName=endpoint_name,
            ContentType='text/plain',
            Body=prompt.encode('utf-8'),
            Accept='text/plain'
        )
        generated_content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        return generated_content[:max_length]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating content: {e}")
        return None

# Test the generate_content function
prompt = "Write a blog post introduction about the benefits of automated marketing platforms."
generated_content = generate_content(prompt)

if generated_content:
    print("Generated Content:")
    print(generated_content)
else:
    print("Failed to generate content.")

I tried increasing my instance count, increase connect timeout, read timeout, retry attempts.. but still I encounter error..
Error:
(env) macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Pro content_generation % python content_generator.py
GPT-2 Model Information:
{'ModelName': 'gpt-2-model', 'Containers': [{'Image': '763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:1.12.1-cpu-py38', 'Mode': 'SingleModel'}], 'ExecutionRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::471112657772:role/sagemaker', 'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 19, 4, 38, 3, 872000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ModelArn': 'arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-north-1:471112657772:model/gpt-2-model', 'EnableNetworkIsolation': False, 'DeploymentRecommendation': {'RecommendationStatus': 'COMPLETED', 'RealTimeInferenceRecommendations': [{'RecommendationId': 'gpt-2-model/pxjHziEz', 'InstanceType': 'ml.c5d.xlarge', 'Environment': {}}, {'RecommendationId': 'gpt-2-model/0TscHZCS', 'InstanceType': 'ml.g4dn.xlarge', 'Environment': {}}, {'RecommendationId': 'gpt-2-model/4pQJVxdM', 'InstanceType': 'ml.c5.2xlarge', 'Environment': {}}]}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'bfeae9be-a458-4e89-baed-9d9954a9f1fe', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'bfeae9be-a458-4e89-baed-9d9954a9f1fe', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '731', 'date': 'Sun, 21 Apr 2024 07:27:19 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
Endpoint Information:
{'EndpointName': 'gpt2-endpoint', 'EndpointArn': 'arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-north-1:471112657772:endpoint/gpt2-endpoint', 'EndpointConfigName': 'gpt2-config', 'ProductionVariants': [{'VariantName': 'default-variant-name', 'DeployedImages': [{'SpecifiedImage': '763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:1.12.1-cpu-py38', 'ResolvedImage': '763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference@sha256:749b039a90e417706ed17cad5c977b5bc380d1dd2ed68b339e17a494ddc97b4c', 'ResolutionTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 20, 14, 20, 57, 370000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}], 'CurrentWeight': 1.0, 'DesiredWeight': 1.0, 'CurrentInstanceCount': 2, 'DesiredInstanceCount': 2}], 'EndpointStatus': 'InService', 'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 19, 10, 7, 28, 593000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'LastModifiedTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 20, 14, 23, 20, 819000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '858530d1-4e9b-458b-a298-bd1837479e25', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '858530d1-4e9b-458b-a298-bd1837479e25', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '704', 'date': 'Sun, 21 Apr 2024 07:27:19 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
Error generating content: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (0) from primary with message "Your invocation timed out while waiting for a response from container primary. Review the latency metrics for each container in Amazon CloudWatch, resolve the issue, and try again.". See https://eu-north-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-north-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/gpt2-endpoint in account 471112657772 for more information.
Failed to generate content.

I’m not too familiar with programming and python, and in search of a mentor.. currently working on a project and I believe I need guidance on it.. be more than happy if an expert here could help

The error message says more detailed information is available in the CloudWatch Logs. You can open the URL included in the error message to see the detailed error. See also this document how SageMaker related log group names are structured.
